# How can I get a reference to the target element with ui-view attribute in ui-router when state change happens

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In this example below, we know that target element to load the template for state1 and state2 is the one with id of "target". When a state change occurs, I would like to be able to get a reference to this element from one of the state change events so that I can add extra classes to it (to show loading indicator, etc).

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <div ui-view id="target"></div>
    <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>
```

UPDATE:
The above scenario is simplistic. Please take into consideration that there may be many views, many named views, or nested views.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your own custom directive on the element where you defined your ui-view. In there you hook up the handlers for the state change events and access the element to add/remove css classes:

HTML:

```
<div ui-view loading></div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app').directive('loading', [
    '$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
                    element.addClass('loading');
                });
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                    element.removeClass('loading');
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FitZEswYUyc97Fvxwxk9?p=preview (Check your console's messages to verify it's working)

Comment: Thanks.  But what if I have multiple views, many sibling named views, or nested views? Then this won't work.

Comment: No, indeed, it won't. You could have mentioned that in your question so i could have spared myself the trouble of giving an answer which does not apply to your usecase.